# Autounlock/Autoreset SSH Auth on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ssh, authentication

are there any tools which cover the following scenario:

1. You have the situation that you have elimentated all ssh accesses by accident and literally no one has  access to the server via ssh. Everyone is locked out and no one has access.
2. Somesort of cron is running on the ubuntu server which checks whether there are successful logins in the last 24h
3. In case no one has access there wont be any succesfull logins, at this point i am looking for a solution which autoreset the whole ssh key system. Do you know any solutions?

Thank in advance
Che

Comment: This seems scriptable. However, it also points to a serious problem with your organization if 1) Such "accidents" are common enough to require such a recovery method (restoring deleted keys? Egad!), and 2) No local or KVM (non-ssh) access is available -- it means you are purchasing the wrong services or using the wrong providers.

Comment: No. Your proposed "autoreset" is logically impossible. You could, via `cron` restore a previous configuration.